# Open an external URL in popup on click in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular6

I am giving a link to the external web address in my angular 4 apps. I need to open the site in a popup without an address bar.

Comment: You mean with an iframe?

Comment: any other alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap modal popup and iframe to render your site.

```
<iframe [src]="yourURL" width="700" height="800" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

check Mozilla documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

In internet explorer, if the new url is from the same domain as the current url, the window will be open without an address bar. Otherwise, it will cause an address bar to appear. One workaround is to open a page from the same domain and then redirect from that page.

```
window.open('https://yourSite.com', 'winname', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you should avoid opening links in a popup window as it is not the best user experience practice, however, you can open up a link using good old `<a>` tag as follows and by putting the `target` property to `popup` you can achieve what you need.

```html
<a href="https://google.com" 
  target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('https://google.com','popup','width=200,height=200,'); return false;">
    Pop Up
</a>
```

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)  you can find more properties that can be set to add more behavior to the popup. i.e. in case, you don't want the user to resize the window you can set `resizable=no` (doesn't work on Chrome*).
P.S. Please check the support of different browsers for the options you need.

Answer (score -2):

you can use like this

```
<a [href]="www.yourlink.com" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to the question (untested), code only answers are discouraged on SO. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to help OP better understand, and to provide greater benefit to future visitors of the site. Thanks!